# Extent Reports Not having Scenario Name

Tags: java, cucumber, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

[My Extent Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XMNT.png)
My Extent report looks like this. How can i add scenario name of feature in the reports like Scenario Outline: **Add Comment to Jira Bug with Valid Data**

What changes to make in onTestStart() so that it can capture scenario name?

```
public class ExtentReportConfigListener implements ITestListener {

    private static ExtentReports extentReports;
    public static ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> extentTest = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
        String fileName = ExtentReportManager.getReportNameWithTimeStamp();
        String fullReportPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\reports\\" + fileName;
        extentReports = ExtentReportManager.createInstance(fullReportPath, "Test API Automation Report",
                "Test ExecutionReport");
    }

    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        if (extentReports != null)
            extentReports.flush();
    }

    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        ExtentTest test = extentReports.createTest(
                "Test Name " + result.getTestClass().getName() + " - " + result.getMethod().getMethodName());
        extentTest.set(test);
    }

    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        ExtentReportManager.logFailureDetails(result.getThrowable().getMessage());
        String stackTrace = Arrays.toString(result.getThrowable().getStackTrace());
        stackTrace = stackTrace.replaceAll(",", "<br>");
        String formmatedTrace = "<details>\n" + "    <summary>Click Here To See Exception Logs</summary>\n" + "    "
                + stackTrace + "\n" + "</details>\n";
        ExtentReportManager.logExceptionDetails(formmatedTrace);
    }

}
```

I am using TestNg listners to trigger the extent report. What am i missing here?